# iOS unit testing instance variables

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I am new to iOS development and I am trying to write unit tests for my code. I need to access instance variables. Is the only way to do this to create a category, write getter methods, and then import that into my test file?

Here is my .m file

```
//imports
@implementation viewController{
    NSArray* a;
    int b;
    //other variables
}

//methods
```

Here is test file

```
#import "ViewController_Tests.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController_Tests{
  ViewController *controller;
}

- (void)setUp {
  [super setUp];
  controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)test1 {
  NSArray* a;
  //I want to access the variables here!

} 

@end
```

Comment: Please provide more detail. What class does the instance variables belong to, your app delegate?

Comment: They are instance variables in a custom class that I created. In the .m file, within the @implementation block, I declared instance variables that I'd like to access.

Comment: Can you create an instance of that class inside the unit test?

Comment: Please provide an example of what is causing you trouble and we can look at that.

Comment: Yes, I can create an instance of the class but I don't have public access to the instance variables.

Comment: In general, unit tests should be performed on methods. Any data or variable should be returned by the method, you shouldn't care about the internals of the object. Try adding accessor methods if you need them.

Comment: Added code to explain what I am trying to do. I prefer not to add code just for tests since I don't need the accessor methods for the normal program. Is there another way or is the best way to just add accessor methods?

Comment: So you wish to test that the view controller performs properly?

Comment: Correct, and I want to access the variables to check if they are the right values, correct states, etc.

Comment: I've posted two solutions, if you need more details/examples feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two solutions you can use:

1: Use UISpec framework to test the function of the view controller, e.g. "assert that view controller has a tableview with X number of entries" (this is a regression test) and runs in the simulator with full GUI.

2: Use precompiler flags such as #ifdef UNIT_TESTS to either open up access to the member variables or add accessor methods, using the build settings define UNIT_TESTS in other preprocessor flags, thus it is only compiled in unit tests.